# How to convert a date with milliseconds into a date with just 000 instead of the milliseconds?

Tags: sql-server

My incoming data contains a date in the following format:

> 2019-05-01 15:20:51.920

but after getting loaded into the target system it gets converted into the following :

> 2019-05-01 15:20:51.000

I would like to convert the source data and compare it with my target system since my target data is as per requirements.

ie `2019-05-01 15:20:51.920` should be converted to `2019-05-01 15:20:51.000`

I am looking at convert functions as follows but it is only trimming the ms (using getdate(0 as a example):

```
select CONVERT(DATETIME2(3),getdate())
--2019-05-01 15:20:51.920
select CONVERT(DATETIME2(2),getdate())
--2019-05-01 15:20:51.92
```

Could someone tell me how I could achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: What does select `CONVERT(DATETIME2(0),getdate())` do? Given what you've written, that's what I'd expect to work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be also a more or less performant way:

```
SELECT GETDATE() AS OriginalValue
, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), GETDATE(), 121)) ValueWithoutMilliseconds
```

The idea behind is to trim milliseconds, by cutting the last 4 characters of a fixed output format and then convert it back to a `datetime`

An output:

```
OriginalValue           |   ValueWithoutMilliseconds
----------------------------------------------------
2019-05-01 21:44:58.473 |   2019-05-01 21:44:58.000
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just cast the fractional seconds portion away using `datetime2(0)`?

```
declare @dateValue datetime2(3) = SysDateTime();

select Convert(datetime2(3), Convert(datetime2(0), @dateValue));
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this should be give result what you are looking for,

> ```
> DECLARE  @TodayDatatime datetime
> SET @TodayDatatime = DateAdd(DAY, DateDiff(DAY, 0, GetDate()), 0)
> select GETDATE()
> SELECT DateAdd(SECOND, DateDiff(SECOND, @TodayDatatime, GetDate()), @TodayDatatime)
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Using the DATEADD/DATEDIFF method to truncate dates can work for this. Another option is to convert to datetime2(0).

```
SELECT DATEADD( SS, DATEDIFF(SS, '2020', aDate), '2020'),
        CAST( aDate AS datetime2(0))
FROM  (VALUES( CAST( '2019-05-01 15:20:51.920' AS datetime2(3))))x(aDate)
```

**Note** that the first option will truncate and the second one will round the value.